# Flow: optional prop that uses generic types

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I've got a react component that has a function prop called `showModal`. I've annotated this function elsewhere using generic types, but here, I want it to be an optional prop. Usually I do that with `func?: () => void`, but that syntax doesn't work in this case (I get `Parsing error` no matter where I place the `?`):

```
type props = {
  showModal<T>(T => React$Node, T): void,
}
```

How do I specify that `showModal` is optional? I've looked through the docs for Flow, but can't find anything relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tweak the function expression. [Flow Try link](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeOAb1LjiYAsIAdwCyEACYoANgH4AXHAA8AFQB8ACiVsViYjAAkAOXFIANHCUBKLXABuEYGJOkAvuTQQAdkywQI8hhDMbJzcvAIi4lLyaihmAEZWrNoArh5iSJjAHkhiLqE8pO5e8HEoUP6MLOxcPPxCohKS8qnpmdm5rjxd3T08QA)

```
type Props = {
  showModal?: <T>(T => React$Node, T) => void,
}

const foo: Props = {
  showModal: (a, b) => undefined
}

const bar: Props = {
  showModal: undefined
}
```